# Redux checkbox second item on list is changing everytime I toggle

Tags: reactjs, redux

So basically the unchecked and checked is working now in redux I already implement it too on api request. But the problem when I clicked the checkbox the second item below is changed too.

I checked todo because it's done
then the todo below in the todo I checked is checked too not sure why

The code below is for complete todo function. I did not include incomplete todo since they both same logic and they both do same in terms on checkbox

[click to see image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPwjs.png)

```
export default function CompletedTodos( { todos } ){
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onToggle = useCallback(id => dispatch(incompleteTodo(id)), [dispatch]);
  const todoComplete = todos.filter(t => t.completed)
  return <Todos todos={todoComplete} completeTodo={onToggle} />;
}
```

```
const Todos = ({ todos, completeTodo }) => (
  <span>
    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <Todo key={index} {...todo} onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)} />
    ))}
  </span>
);

export default Todos;
```

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, id, completed, title }) => (
    <li className={`task-info ui-sortable-handle ${completed ? "line-through" : "none"}`} id="task17">
        {completed ? <CompleteTodo completed={true} onClick={onClick} /> : <IncompleteTodo id={id} completed={false} onClick={onClick} />}

        {title}
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
        <div className="mt-3">
            <p className="float-right mb-0 mt-2">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-sm waves-effect waves-light">View</button>
            </p>
            <p className="mb-0">
                <a href="" className="text-muted"><img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png" alt="task-user" className="thumb-sm rounded-circle mr-2" /> <span className="font-bold font-secondary">Maya Didas</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
);
```

```
import React from "react";

const CompleteTodo = ({ onClick, completed }) => {
    return (
        <div className="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-single float-right">
            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Single checkbox Two" onClick={onClick} defaultChecked={completed}/>
            <label></label>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CompleteTodo;
```

Comment: For lists which get updated, never use the index as the key. Use `todo.id`, since it's a unique identifier

Answer (score 2):

Thank for Jayce444 for helping on this.

Answer 
For lists which get updated, never use the index as the key. Use todo.id, since it's a unique identifier